# Average of elements in ArrayList

Tags: java

```
public static int averageInArrayList(ArrayList <Integer> arrayList) {
    Integer sum = 0;
    if(!ArrayList.isEmpty()) {
        for (Integer sum : ArrayList) {
            sum += ArrayList;
        }
        double total = sum.doubleValue() / ArrayList.size();
    }
    return total;
}
```

Hi I'm having trouble returning the average of all the elements in the Arraylist 
(also not quite sure if my first line is correct)

Comment: Type cast your variable total to int because you are returning int type

Comment: There's actually no need to check whether the arrayList is empty.

Comment: You should always prefer primitive types to boxed primitives. `Integer sum = 0;` should be replaced by `int sum = 0;`. The return type should be `double` instead of `int`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use the lambda way?

```
List<Integer> testList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

double intAverage = testList.stream()
    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
    .average()
    .orElse(0.0);

System.out.println(intAverage);
```

As a method:

```
public static double averageList(List<Integer> testList) {
     return testList.stream()
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .average()
        .orElse(0.0);
}
```

Comment: I'm given an Arraylist and I have to return the average

Comment: Ohhh nearly!! uh so another test failed when the array is empty { } and I need to return 0.00

Comment: How would I add that in

Comment: @qwert123 fixed

Answer (score 2):

**Java 8**

```
public static double calculateAverage(List<Integer> list) {
    return list
            .stream()
            .mapToInt(number -> number)
            .average().getAsDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare `double total` outside of the condition scope otherwise it won't be available. Put it one line below `sum`. Also you have to change your return type to `double` since you are no longer returning an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change your return type to Double (the average is not an integer) and change your stream into DoubleStream for effective computing:

```
public static double averageInArrayList(ArrayList <Integer> arrayList) {
    return arrayList
            .stream()
            .mapToDouble(Integer::doubleValue)
            .average()
            .orElse(0.0D);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private double calculateAverage(List <Integer> marks) {
  Integer sum = 0;
  if(!marks.isEmpty()) {
    for (Integer mark : marks) {
        sum += mark;
    }
    return sum.doubleValue() / marks.size();
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying: cannot find symbol pointing to the List <Integer> in first line

Comment: Hi @Jamez, I would be really helpful for the person who asked the question, and others who might view your answer in the future, to explain your answer and not just dump code.

Comment: What are you saying? This is a example from me in my code. I will show him what i have in my code and he can the structure for him code.

Answer (score -1):

Just change three lines and you'll be fine.

```
public static double averageInArrayList(List <Integer> ArrayList) { //line 1
    Integer sum = 0;
    if(!ArrayList.isEmpty()) {
        for (Integer element: ArrayList) {  //line 2
            sum += element;                 //line 3
        }
        double total = sum.doubleValue() / ArrayList.size();
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Pointing to return total - error cant find symbol, i don't know why

Comment: `total` is out of return scope.

Comment: you've declared `total` inside `if` block and returned it outside it. please revise your answer.